# How to use the xmlconcat function in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I want to use xmlconcat function so that my xml looks like below:

```
<BusProcess>
<CRR>
<CUSIP>65443W404</CUSIP>
<RUP>100</RUP>
<ACB>2500</ACB>
</CRR>
<LEI>546</LEI>
<AddModCDIC>
<CDICData>
<UCIData>
<UCI>BMO2100001200001</UCI>
<InterestlnDeposit>50</InterestlnDeposit>
</UCIData>
<UCIData>
<UCI>BMO2100005500012</UCI>
<InterestlnDeposit>50</InterestlnDeposit>
</UCIData>
</CDICData>
</AddModCDIC>
</BusProcess>
```

Can someone help to debug my code to get the above result

```
select XMLELEMENT ("BusProcess",XMLFOREST(
XMLFOREST('65443W404' as "CUSIP",100 as "RUP", 2500 as "ACB") as "CRR",
(CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN XMLCONCAT (xmlelement ("LEI",a.vcud_lei ),XMLELEMENT("CDICData", 
XMLAGG(  XMLELEMENT("UCIData",xmlforest(a.vcud_uci as "UCI",a.vcud_per as "InterestlnDeposit")))))  
END ) as "AddModCDIC") )

from vw_cdic_uci_detail a 
where vcud_clcode in ('21000055','21000012');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH vw_cdic_uci_detail AS ( SELECT 546 AS vcud_lei, 'BMO2100001200001' AS vcud_uci, 50 AS vcud_per FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                             SELECT 546 AS vcud_lei, 'BMO2100005500012' AS vcud_uci, 50 AS vcud_per FROM DUAL
                           )
SELECT XMLELEMENT( "BusProcess",
          XMLFOREST(
             XMLFOREST( '65443W404' AS "CUSIP",
                        100         AS "RUP",
                        2500        AS "ACB"
             ) AS "CRR"
          ),
          XMLELEMENT("LEI", vcud_lei),
          XMLCONCAT( AddModCDIC ) AS "AddModCDIC"
       )
  FROM ( SELECT vcud_lei,
                CASE
                   WHEN 1=1
                   THEN
                   XMLCONCAT(
                      XMLELEMENT("AddModCDIC",
                         XMLELEMENT("CDICData",
                            XMLAGG(
                                     XMLELEMENT("UCIData",
                                        XMLFOREST(vcud_uci AS "UCI",
                                                  vcud_per AS "InterestlnDeposit"
                                  )
                               )
                            )
                         )
                      )
                   ) 
                   ELSE NULL
                END AS AddModCDIC
           FROM vw_cdic_uci_detail
          GROUP BY vcud_lei
      ) a;
```

Comment: Hi Thomas,Can you please help to fit this subquery within the main query ,I have given that details in the below answer tab