# how to add a subquery to existing main code

Tags: xml, oracle

*Can you please help me with the right code ,so that I can populate LEIvalue once for the aggregated UCIDATA block in my below code.
*My output xml should look like below:**

```
<BusProcess>
<CRR>
<CUSIP>65443W404</CUSIP>
<RUP>100</RUP>
<ACB>2500</ACB>
</CRR>
<LEI>549300B2SAXGWM7G5218</LEI>
<AddModCDIC>
<CDICData>
<UCIData>
<UCI>BMO2100001200001</UCI>
<InterestlnDeposit>50</InterestlnDeposit>
</UCIData>
<UCIData>
<UCI>BMO2100005500012</UCI>
<InterestlnDeposit>50</InterestlnDeposit>
</UCIData>
</CDICData>
</AddModCDIC>
</BusProcess>
```

My code to be corrected to get the above output is as below:
In the below code I am not able to retrieve the value of LEI.Can you please help me to correct my code below to get the above output format

```
  `select xmlElement("BusProcess",
            xmlElement("CRR",
              xmlForest(ncm_real_cusip as "CUSIP",ltrim(to_char(nch_qtytot,'999999990.0099')) as "RUP", ltrim(to_char(nvl(nch_adjusted_cost_base_cad, 0), '99999999999990.0099')) as "ACB")),
              (
                               select xmlelement("AddModCDIC",
                                               xmlelement("CDICdata",
                                                          xmlelement("LEI",vcud_lei),XMLAGG(
                                                                                         XMLELEMENT("UCIData",
                                                                                                    xmlforest(a.vcud_uci as "UCI",a.vcud_uci/* a.vcud_sia_flag*/ as "SIAIndividualFlg", a.vcud_per as "InterestlnDeposit")
                                                                                                   )
                                                                                        )
                                                           )
                                               ) 
                                               
                       from vw_cdic_uci_detail a ,mf_nfu_updates_stg,holding,nfu_crr_message,nfu_crr_accounts
    where vcud_clcode = mnus_clcode
    and mnus_cdicflag ='Y'
    and vcud_clcode = nca_clcode
    and nca_clcode = ho_clcode
    --and ( ho_cusip = NCM_CUSIP or ho_cusip = NCM_REAL_CUSIP )
    and ncm_msgid  = nca_msgid  )
                      
                                      
         )
                                                             
    from nfu_crr_message,nfu_crr_holding,nfu_crr_accounts,nfu_crr_ip o,tb_title t,tb_resid r, vw_tb_resid
    where ncm_msgid = nch_msgid
    and nch_msgid  = nca_msgid(+)
    and nch_clcode = nca_clcode(+)
    and nch_acctyp = nca_acctyp(+)
    and nch_chkdig = nca_chkdig(+)
    and nch_msgid  = ncp_msgid(+)
    and nch_clcode = ncp_clcode(+)
    and nch_acctyp = ncp_acctyp(+)
    and nch_chkdig = ncp_chkdig(+)
    and ncp_title  = t.code(+)
    and upper(ncp_country) = upper(decode(ncp_lang, 'F',country_F(+), country_E(+)))
    and nca_resid  = r.code(+)
    and ncp_type(+)   = 'O'
    and ncm_msgid  = '843'`
```

Comment: This is the same question as before. But I can't understand all your additional code.  [How to use the xmlconcat function in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043242/how-to-use-the-xmlconcat-function-in-oracle)

Comment: You have to group by vcid_lei as I have already shown you in the example.

Comment: But When I try to fit this subquery to the main query its states too many values.As there is one more externl from clause in the main query